# Is it possible to trade Pokemon from a first gen cart/ROM to the 3DS Virtual Console?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, emulation, pokemon-red-blue-yellow-green, virtual-console

I have found a tool that explains older generations to new generations through ROMs, but I'm not able to find information on doing a direct trade.

I'm looking to get Pokémon from my ROM version of Pokémon Yellow to my 3DS Virtual Console version of Pokémon Yellow. Is this possible?

Comment: if you have acess to a file manager on the 3ds can you navigate to root storage and just copy/paste your .sav file?